# Using 2 actions in the same view, index and show ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, action

How can i make a view index working with 2 actions show and index in the same view ??? I`m new in ruby on rails.

Comment: Use `redirect_to` or `render`.

Comment: I`m tried to use render, but in the index i have a sidebar, which lists the news and in the center of the page i need to show a notice with the id, and if i use the render i have to duplicate my code in show.html.haml and index.hatml.haml. Have no other way ???

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear why you'd want a `show` method to be the same as an `index` but the easiest approach is to redirect:

```
def show
  redirect_to(:action => :index)
end
```

The alternative is to render the same template:

```
def show
  render(:action => 'index')
end
```

If you're using the `render` method you will have to populate the same instance variables as in the `index` method or your view may not be able to run. If you want to be sure that the same variables are set, you can also do this:

```
def show
  self.index
  render(:action => 'index')
end
```